# Let$f ∈ L^3(1,+∞)$, and let $g(x) = f(e^x)$ for x ∈ (0,+∞). Prove that $ g ∈ L^2(0,+∞).$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let$f ∈ L^3(1,+∞)$, and let $g(x) = f(e^x)$ for x ∈ (0,+∞). Prove that $ g ∈ L^2(0,+∞).$
I am beginner in Real and functional analysis. My question: To solve this question should I start with definiton or some other methods/tricks.

Comment: Maybe try a Change of Variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [u-sub on Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259750/substitution-rule-in-the-sense-of-lebesgue-integral) for justification of a change of variable. (You need this justified since $f$ may not be continuous.) Anyways, by u-sub,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty [f(e^x)]^2\, \mathrm{d}x=\int_1^\infty [f(y)]^2 e^{-y}\, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}
By Holder's inequality with $p=3/2, q=3,$ we can say above is less than $||f||_3^2\, ||e^{-y}||_3<\infty.$

Comment: If I exchange  e^x with for example  x^2+1 the statement is valid.

Comment: The $e^{-y}$ term gets replaced with $1/y.$ What happens to this in the $L^3$ norm?

Comment: I/y belongs to L^1(1,infinity)

Comment: That's not even true (harmonic series)

Comment: I am sorry you are right. I just figured that